# How can I disable the beep when I plug in/unplug my laptop's AC adapter?

Tags: laptop, power

My Packard-Bell laptop is emitting a loud, annoying beep when I connect or disconnect it to/from an AC power source.

Whether I have headphones plugged in or not does not change anything; the sound goes out of the speakers and wakes everyone up.

Do you know of any ways to eliminate this sound? I searched around the Internet and found a solution involving setting a specific volume bar to 0 in the playback settings, but I did not find it on my laptop. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6jP9MfOSMg

Comment: @Phil Yes, that is the solution I am referring to in my question. The specified volume bar does not exist in my settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the option that will matter to you is the `Power Control Beep`. It's a BIOS setting, so you'll have to restart your computer to change it.

1. Either restart your computer, or shut it down and then power it back on.
2. When the boot process starts, open the BIOS settings menu. How you do this depends on your computer. Usually, it involves pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> on the first screen that comes up, **before** the "Starting Windows" animation appears.
3. In the BIOS settings, use the arrow keys — directions should be provided on-screen — to navigate to the `Config` menu, then the `Alarm` sub-menu.
4. Set `Power Control Beep` to "disabled." If you want to get rid of other beeping at the same time, you can set `Low Battery Alarm` and `Password Beep` to "disabled" as well.
5. Save and exit the BIOS settings application. Again, directions for this should be on screen. In my case, it was as easy as pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Depending on your computer, you may be asked which device you want to boot from. Select whatever you usually use (typically the HDD, or hard drive).
7. Tell your family members that they will no longer be woken up by your computer.

Comment: I will try that at the next reboot, thanks. Did you delete your previous answer ? It could have interested bypassers..

Comment: @Dunaril, yeah, I did. While it may be interesting to someone, it's pretty explicitly wrong for your question.

Answer (score 1):

- open the "sound" settings in control panel
- in the "Playback" tab select the playback device (Conexant high def...) then click the properties box at the bottom
- go to the "Levels" tab and there you will see 2 volume bars
- Mute the "Pc speaker"

Answer (score 1):

Acer Aspire 5740G solution to this problem: don't install (or uninstall) the Realtek audio driver. The notebook will run fine and have all audio functionalities with the built-in Windows driver.

(I have Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate. 100% working. I am very happy.)

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to do this:

Open registries by searching `regedit` in the start menu. Then go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound` and on the `Beep` registry change the value to `No`.

Source with more ways to do this: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-system-beep-windows-7-8

Comment: Might be worth noting that this probably disables all beeps, not just the power related beeps.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions I searched for worked for me, but I figured it out!

Go to Settings > Sound > Sound Control Panel > Right Click on "Speakers Realtek(R) Audio" and click Disable

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

For people not finding a solution with the above options, and that could not find the second speaker volume adjustment :

- Go to packardbell.com
- Go to support
- Go to downloads and go for your model number ( EasyNote is "EN TJ**" )
- Go to drivers
- Look for the Conexant audio driver and download it (be sure to check you are downloading for Win 32 or 64 bits)
- Install the driver
- Right-click the speaker icon to the bottom right corner of the screen
- Select playback devices (2nd option from top)
- Click on the speaker icon, then on properties
- Click on the level tab (2nd one from left)
- You should now see a second set of volume sliders (installed by update)
- Click on the mute button of the second one called PC Speaker
- Done

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Also, If you haven't found "power beeps" in BIOS, remove Realtek Audio driver and refresh device configuration from device manager. It'll install default audio driver. Sound works, no beeps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was disable the battery driver and driver of the adapter in the devices manager, the downside is that I lose the battery level in the task bar.