# Disable beep sound when plugging/unplugging laptop charger

Tags: windows-10, laptop, charger, system-sounds

My issue is the same as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/243955/how-can-i-disable-the-beep-when-i-plug-in-unplug-my-laptops-ac-adapter), but none of the answers there helped solving my problem, so I'm hoping to get alternative suggestions here.

My laptop (Acer Aspire S5-391 with Windows 10 Home 64 bit) makes an annoying beep sound whenever I plug or unplug the charger, which I'd like to disable.

The following solutions I found in the linked question and in other places **did not work for me**:

- My BIOS doesn't provide a setting for [power control beep](https://superuser.com/a/244794/644565).
- My [playback device settings](https://superuser.com/a/272602/644565) don't show the "PC speaker" bar, so I can't mute it.
- I don't have the Realtek audio driver, so I can't [uninstall it](https://superuser.com/a/880835/644565). When I automatically search for a new audio driver via device manager, the search won't terminate. When I donwload the driver from the Acer Support site, I am only offered the Realtek driver (which seems to be a possible cause of the problem according to some sites) which anyway fails to install.
- My device manager doesn't show [Non-Plug and Play Drivers](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-system-beep-windows-7-8), even after enabling "Show hidden devices", and therefore I can't see and disable the "Beep" device.  *According to LPChip's comment on DavidPostill's answer, in Windows 10 the "Beep" entry is labelled as "System devices" > "System speakers", so see the next bullet point.*
- *Edit after DavidPostill's updated answer* My device manager doesn't show ["system speakers"](https://superuser.com/a/1127638/644565) under "system devices" (which seems to be the equivalent to the above for Windows 10), so I can't disable them. Possibly my laptop doesn't have separate system speakers so the beep comes from the normal built-in speakers, in which case I probably won't be able to manipulate something in the device manager without also affecting all other sounds.
- ["Default beep" in the system sounds](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-system-beep-windows-7-8) I already have disabled (so this apparently isn't the correct option anyway).

Gloabally disabling sounds mutes the beep, but is not a desired workaround for me - I only want to get rid of the charger beep, but still want to hear other default system sounds (or at least some, I alreay configured these in the control panel, but didn't find an option specifically for the charger beep; I think this is a matter of driver or BIOS settings rather than default Windows settings, but am not completely sure).

Comment: Can't post as an answer as I don't have adequate experience. But what worked for me is going to Sound Settings> Advanced Options. This shows a list of apps for which you can adjust the sound at a percentage of master volume. With this screen open, if you un/plug your machine, Realtek HD Audio Manager pops up on screen. Set the sound to 0 for this and the beeping should stop.

Comment: palsrealm's answer above worked for me on an Acer Triton 300 SE (Windows 11). 

1. Search for "Sound Settings" in the control panel (breadcrumbs will say System > Sound)

2. Scroll down to Advanced section and click Volume Mixer

3. Turn volume to 0 (and mute) the one called "Realtek HD Audio Universal Service"

Answer (score 4):

#### My laptop makes an annoying beep sound whenever I plug or unplug the charger.

**Windows 8.1/Windows 10:**

Disable the `System Speaker` device:

1. Open "Device Manager".
2. Scroll down to "System Devices".
3. Click on "+"
4. Right click on "System Speaker".
5. Select "Disable"
6. Restart your computer.

Beep should be permanently disabled.

---

**Windows 7:**

Disable the `Beep` device:

> 1. Open "Device Manager".
> 2. Go to "View" > "Show hidden devices".
> 3. Scroll down to "Non-Plug and Play Drivers".
> 4. Click on "+"
> 5. Right click on "Beep".
> 6. Select "Disable"
> 7. Restart your computer.
>
> Beep should be permanently disabled.
>
> [image]

Source [Disabling awful power cord beep?](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/disabling-awful-power-cord-beep.455372/)

Comment: As I already wrote in my question, this did not work for me, since I don't see "Non-Plug and Play Drivers" in my device manager, even after enabling "Show hidden devices".

Comment: @lemontree "In Windows 10 and in Windows 8.1, the hidden devices will be listed in their usual categories of devices, but they will be grayed out. Also, you will notice that more categories of devices are displayed."

Comment: Ah, found it. Its labelled as system devices > System Speaker

Comment: @LChip and DavidPostill Thanks for the update, but unfortunately I don't see "System Speaker" in "System Devices" either. Annoyingly, the devices are named entirely differently in the German version and I can't figure out any entry that would match something like "system speaker". I think that "High Definition Audio-Controller" is the normal speaker driver, but what is requied instead must be some kind of internal speakers which I can't find. If it is of any help, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/itF0m.png) is everything I see under "system devices".

Comment: @lemontree According to https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx it should be "Systemlautsprecher"

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah, this site is helpful, I'll remember it. Sadly, "Systemlautsprecher" doesn't appear in my device manager either, neither under "System devices" ("Systemeräte") nor in any of the other categories.

Comment: @lemontree Maybe your laptop doesn't have a system speaker ... and the beeps are therefore coming from the built in normal speakers.

Comment: In this case, I guess changing something in the device manager won't help? Because I obivously can't just disable my normal speakers without also effecting the other sounds.

Comment: @lemontree Yes. I'm out of ideas. Note "so i've been down this path and have emailed and called acer about this. They state there is no way to disable the sound as "it is enabled by default." lame excuse but that's what they say. " from the same link in my answer ...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you still need this answered but I had the same problem, and it doesn't look like it was answered here.

1. Right click on your sound icon and open sound settings.
2. Sound > Advanced Sound Options > App volume and device preferences
3. Pull out or plug in your power cord and Realtek HD Audio Manager should
   appear
4. Set to Zero and enjoy blessed silence

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using Acer Aspire 5. Everything is working fine. Audio and mic are OK. Except for the annoying beep when I plug in/unplug the charger.

So here is the fix that I found that just gets rid of the annoying beep. (The audio and mic still work.)

1. Uninstall the Realtek Audio driver (restart required)
2. Download the Realtek (driver only) from the Realtek official website.
3. Install it and SHAZAM!!!! The annoying beep is gone.
4. One last thing. You need to prevent the driver from automatically updating.(Google it.)

Comment: I was skeptical but after trying all the registry/cmd hacks which didn't, this actually worked. Or may be the all previous hacks were *enabled* by this last driver! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for my PC operating on Windows 11 is:

1. Turning off my PC
2. While booting up the PC press F12-key
3. Going to Configuration-tab in the BIOS menu (using the arrow-keys)
4. Disabling the Power sound option
5. Pressing F10 to Save and Exit the menu
6. Plugging in the charger and the sound is Gone for good

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to follow the steps and check if it helps.

Disable the PC Speakers and check if it helps.

- Right click on Sound Icon in the task bar and go to Playback devices.
- Select Speaker and click on properties.
- Go to Levels tab, and mute (or you can reduce it) PC Speaker and check if it helps.

Comment: I stated in my post that simply disabling all sounds is not a proper solution for me.